# obtener imagen de mysql desde android según el id de la imagen

Tags: mysql, imagen

¿Alguien sabrá decirme si se puede obtener unas imágenes desde Mysql desde Android según un id solicitado? O sea, lo que quiero hacer es una persona seleccione el nombre de una empresa y la aplicación le devuelva su logotipo. Estas imágenes están almacenadas en una base de datos Mysql. Desde ya les agradecería la ayuda ya que soy nuevo en Android.

Comment: Claro que si se puede, solamente tienes que crear una tabla en tu base de datos, donde coloques una columna para el id, otra donde guardes la imagen en base64, y te recomiendo agregues otras para gurdar parametros como la fecha en la que se guardo, etc. y desde android solamente mandas a guardar o leer el base64 en base al id del registro.

Comment: Hola amigo, cómo estás? en esta empresa lo guardan en blob a la imagen. Se podrá tomar esa imagen desde la base de datos y dejarla almacenada en al app para que la proxima vez que habrá la app no tenga que descargarla? Muchas gracias y si tienes un ejemplo del cual me pueda guiar te lo agradecería aun más porque soy bastante nuevo en esto de android